# How do i add jquery ui date picker, while already working with bootstrap library?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm playing around with bootstrap and i was going to add a datepicker to the page using it, but without any success.. So i found the code for a datepicker, using query ui: [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

And tried this in a new html page, and it worked like a charm. However, i now want to use this in the page i was working on, but it seems like there are some conflicts between the different scripts and css files. Is there a way to solve this?

(i have delated the content of the page but left the scripts and links i'm importing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Svensk Bridge</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/list-function.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i were to import all the files for the jquery ui for the date picker, it won't work.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

So, to sum up: Can i implement the jquery ui datepicker into my already existing document? And which scripts and links get prioritized?

Regards,
Bill

Comment: yes, simply include the css in the top, and then jQuery UI.js at the bottom right after jQuery

Comment: Why not use something already bootstrap friendly? Unless there is a requirement to use the specific jquery one I would recommend something like http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/  It would work very similar to what you are using.  You can fire whatever logic necessary when the user changes the date with their changeDate and onRender events

Comment: To Kevin: No, that did not work.
To jstx: I tried to implement eyecon, but i don't get how to! Pretty frustrating. Don't know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/34681761/2333214

Answer (score 8):

I am using Bootstrap with Jquery UI datepicker, the problem must be the order in which you import things.
Here my order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: THIS was the perfect solution.  I've been trying to figure out what the heck for DAYS why I couldn't use JQuery's datepicker over bootstraps.  This is exactly what I was looking for!  People ask why?  IMHO, JQuery's looks nicer out of the box and is configured easier.  Thank you Kil.

Comment: Use bootstrap date picker instead.

Answer (score 5):

You could, but my personal preference would be to add a Bootstrap-style datepicker instead.  I've been using this one and it's pretty great. http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

The advantage here is that you don't actually need to include the jQuery UI library for this.

Comment: That was what i was trying to add at first, but i did not get how to.. =/

Comment: Could you please give me a jsfiddle example, that would be very appreciated!

Comment: Look at the code examples on that page, any JS fiddle I would make would just be a copy/paste of that code.