# Using JQuery's datepicker with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-4

Before I added bootstrap 4 to my jQuery project, the datepicker looked like this:

[image]

After I added bootstrap 4, then the datepicker looks like this:

[image]

I assume that it is only the formatting/size that has been changed. How do I stop the formatting being over-ridden and to get it to look like the original?

I have tried the following.

1. Calling the datepicker using `jquery` instead of `$`
2. Calling `$.fn.datepicker.noConflict();` (I do not seem to be able to apply `noConflict` to the datepicker functionality, only to jQuery as a whole) as per [jQuery ui datepicker conflict with bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277563/jquery-ui-datepicker-conflict-with-bootstrap-datepicker/34681761?noredirect=1#comment87297573_34681761)

Alternatively, I tried to fix the bootstrap so that the calendar looked more decent and the arrow buttons didn't jump around.

1. Trying to use a bootstrap specific datepicker (although it is unclear to me which one works with Bootstrap 4 and whether I can add tooltip holidays to it using the `beforeShowDay` method, which is a prerequisite for my application)

The HTML code is like this:

```
<TD class="labelH5">Open Date:</TD>
<TD>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <INPUT TYPE="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
      </div>
    </div>
</TD>
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the only solution to your problem is that you write custom template for datepicker with different css classes and define them in a separate css file and copy css code from bootstrap v3 css.

Comment: Is bootstrap 4 applying css to the classes added by jQuery UI?

Comment: @T J. Maybe. (I added the HTML to my question)

Comment: @user1735921: Thanks! Hoping still for something simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **workaround** comes from @Jimmy Stenke's answer in [How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

I added

```
<style>
 div.ui-datepicker {
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
```

after

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I also **deleted** a reference to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sunny/jquery.ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```