# Different calenders are opening on boostrap 4 datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Two different calenders pop up on bootstrap datepicker, dependinding on if I click on the input box or down arrow.
I also have jquery datetime inputs not sure if it is conflicting, I tried resolving with the suggested answer here [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277563/jquery-ui-datepicker-conflict-with-bootstrap-datepicker) but it didnt work (issue is still there)

HTML

```
   <input class="form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="date"id="datepicker">
```

javascript

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({

});
```

> Below is displayed on click of arrow

[image]

> Below is displayed on click of input

[image]

Comment: This is a conflict between Bootstrap datepicker and the browser's built-in picker for `type="date"`. I suggest using `type="text"` or not using Bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: Ok thanks, its seems like bootstrap 4 datepicker is almost completely non-functional, I have spent many hours trying to correctly implement it . Can you reference a fully functional example