# how do I include an external javascript file with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to include an external javascript file while I am using the bootstrap framework.  I figure it should be very simple to do but it seems to be giving me fits.

I have `scripts/dsc.js` that I am trying to load into a `<div id="loadedContent"></div>`

The line of code in the JSP file is:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="loadLocation('content/current.jsp');return false;">View Job (All Runs)</a></li>
```

in the external javascript file I have this as my simple javascript:

```
$(function() {
    alert("Hi");

    loadlLocation = function(location) {
        $("#includedContent").load(location);
    };
});
```

I put this in the head declaration:

```
<script src="scripts/dsc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know that the `src` path is correct because the other includes for the bootstrap scripts work just fine.  The alert located in the `dsc.js` is not showing up with is pointing me to it not being included.  Now, Bootstrap by default was loaded at the bottom (so I left it there), but I included my javascript file in the head declaration.  Is there something special that I have to do to include javascript files when using Bootstrap?

Comment: Do you get a `404 File Not Found` error? or any other kind of javascript error in your console?

Comment: `loadLocation()` is defined in a private scope so is not available using an inline handler (which is global or `window`). Attach the `click` using `$.on()` within the inner scope where it is defined.

Comment: What does loading a js file have to do with using twitter bootstrap? (Inline js - I guess that possibly explains the confusion).

Comment: I got a $ reference is undefined.  I moved the jquery include to inside of the <head> declaration and the alert is now working.  I almost have this working.  The taglib's do not want to import, but that might be another question.

Comment: @Skwal I don't get a 404-error, but I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined and Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' which seems to point to Flot not being loaded.

Comment: Did you include `bootstrap-datepicker.js` in your code? After jquery?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use JQuery's UI datepicker library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually ended up being an ordering problem.  Was already solved here by KirKill.

[How do i add jquery ui date picker, while already working with bootstrap library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934063/how-do-i-add-jquery-ui-date-picker-while-already-working-with-bootstrap-library)

Answer (score 0):

That cant work! You have no access outside the jQuery Wrapper!

```
 var loadlLocation = function(location) {
      $(function() {
           $("#includedContent").load(location);
      });
 };
```