# Date-picker not working when hosting locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery ui 1.11.1 and have hosted it locally. When giving the extensions from the online source the datepicker works fine, but when I host it locally it doesn't.

> Online extensions

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

> Locally hosted extensions

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="date/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="date/jquery-ui.css">
```

The directory is correct and also have followed the order mentioned in the answer in the link below, but yet it doesn't seem to work. Anything else I have missed out? Appreciate any help / suggestion.

[**Click here to View the question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934063/how-do-i-add-jquery-ui-date-picker-while-already-working-with-bootstrap-library)

Answer (score 0):

You said locally, I assume on `file:///` protocol. Therefore, your online scripts fallback to `file:///` protocol. Fix it by adding http/https:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work while hosting it locally, not from the online source.

Comment: You are working from file protocol or on a localhost server?